# iOS - How does caching work?

Tags: ios, swift, caching, nsurlcache

I am working on an app representing JSON from web API.

The remote source updates several times a day.

All I want to do is:

```
// pseudo code

makeRequest() {   
 if (network not available){

  if (cache not exists) {
      showEmptyScreen()
  }else if (cache exists){
      useCache()
  }

 }else if (network available){

    if (cache not exists) {   
        loadFromRemote()
    }else if (cache exists){
        if (cache is older than latest update) {
           loadFromrRemote()
        }else {
           useCache()
        }
    } 
 }
}
```

I've read about `NSURLCache` from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLCache_Class/) and from [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/).

It's still confusing that if NSURLCache could do what I want. For instance, how does it work to check if there's a newer version of data without really download anything?

And if NSURLCache could not handle the checking, how could I code it myself?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How caching behaves is mostly up to you and your server. `NSURLCache` does not make decisions on its own other than perhaps what to do when its capacity limit is exceeded.

When you are making a request, headers like `If-Modified-Since` will determine if data is transferred or not by comparing the timestamps of the cached data.

Server based headers such as `Cache-Control` can also affect how long data remains valid in the cache.

In summary, `NSURLCache` can handle what you need but the implementation will be based on a combination of the configuration of `NSURLCache`, how you make requests, how cache control is implemented in responses and whether you override the policies given by the headers.